# Why does python print even if I don't type print?

Tags: python, string, shell, console

```
print "a"; "b"
```

Will output:

```
"a"
'b'
```

Simply typing an int or string into the console will cause it to print.

```
1
```

Will output:

```
1
```

Is there a reason or benefit for this?

Comment: Just a note: Returning is different from printing

Comment: If an expression is entered into the interpreter, its value will be printed (unless the value is `None`).

Answer (score 5):

The interactive Python interpreter is a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop):

> a simple, interactive computer programming environment that takes single user inputs (i.e. single expressions), evaluates them, and returns the result to the user

What you are seeing is the *return value* for each statement. Consider a slightly less simple example where the return value is different from the input:

```
>>> 2 + 3
5
```

The tight feedback loop provided by a REPL can be especially helpful when exploring a new language or problem domain.