# Why does Python print a value in the body of a loop when I don't use print?

Tags: python

I understand that [the Python interpreter is a REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706923/why-does-python-print-even-if-i-dont-type-print)... but in a loop, the "value" of the loop must be single-valued... correct? And yet I see this (tested in both Python 2.7.18 and 3.8.5 with `range` instead of `xrange`):

```
>>> for _ in xrange(5):
...   3
...
3
3
3
3
3
```

**Where is this behavior documented in Python?**

It seems to get suppressed when in a called function:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   1
...   x
...   return x+1
...
>>> foo(5)
6
>>> def bar(n):
...   for x in xrange(5):
...     1
...     x
...   return n+1
...
>>> bar(5)
6
>>> for x in xrange(5):
...   1
...   x
...
1
0
1
1
1
2
1
3
1
4
```

---

**Note to downvoters: This is not an obvious behavior!** Contrast with Javascript:

```
> for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    i
}
4
```

Comment: This is not a feature of python; it's a feature of this REPL. Save your code to a `.py` file and run it with the interpreter; nothing will be printed.

Comment: Evidently the repl shows the result of every expression executed as a statement, not just the outer statement (the for-loop). The for-loop itself does not have any value at all: it is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @khelwood ok that comment is the closest I've seen to a good answer ("expression executed as a statement" being the key phrase here) and I guess it gets handled differently in deferred execution (`def` or `class` blocks) than in immediate execution in the interpreter.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to explicitly put the word "Python" in the title of your question because it's _tagged_ "python". See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @martineau ...and the reason I continue to do so, despite mod efforts to the contrary, is because SO has instances where you see suggested/search results with only the title and not tags. (See Linked and Related items on the right) And therefore it is not enough to assume that a question can be disambiguated through its tag. The title needs to give sufficient context.

Comment: When you do a search on stackoverflow, you can distinguish between tags and text by enclosing the tags within `[]` brackets. i.e. `[python]`. It gets very tedious and is a waste of bandwidth and resources for everyone to redundantly put the tags associated with their question into its title.

Comment: And it gets tedious to see SO suggested/search results **without** such context. Please read the comments on the meta.SE question you cited. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the "value" of the loop that's resulting in 3 being displayed. It's the result of the interpreter evaluating `3.__repr__()` on each iteration of the loop.

For instance if you instead evaluated `i` you would get the following.

```py
for i in range(5):
   i
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

If you want a for loop that doesn't display anything you'll want to make sure that all statements in the loop don't print anything when evaluated in the interpreter. An example of such a statement would be.

```py
for i in range(5):
    _ = None
```

The reason that for loops don't have a "final value" (unlike your javascript example) is because in Python for loops are statements, and statements in Python don't have a value.

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter will print out any variables you just type out ..

It's just a convenience function.

If you type in "3" in the interpreter, it will also print out "3".

Comment: But that's different. I didn't type "3" 5 times, I typed a `for` statement once.

Comment: @JasonS Well, the python REPL has decided to interpret that `for`-loop as a succession of 5 statements. A different REPL might make a different design decision.

Comment: Maybe... but where is it documented in Python that it would work this way?

Comment: @JasonS Don't know. The first place I would look would be [Appendix / Interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#tut-interac)

Comment: found it under "expression statements" in the Python docs

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using Python interactive interpreter (REPL). REPL always calls the **repr** method of the object. In your case it is **3**.

If you try creating a .py file of this code and run it. Nothing will be printed and the program will just run and close.

Comment: `__repr__`, not `__str__`

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing levels of abstraction.  Every statement has its value.  In the case of your loop, you interpret the line `3` five times, and thus have five non-empty results returned.  The interactive interpreter prints that value each time.

To see it a little more clearly, change the expression:

```
for i in range(5):
    i
```

Comment: I'm not confusing levels of abstraction. What I'm asking is why a compound block in the Python REPL would result in printing individual statement values.

Comment: Exactly: you're seeing this *only* as the abstraction of a loop expression.  This is evaluated as a "compound block"; it is executed, one line at a time.

Comment: and in a function this gets suppressed?

Comment: I meant to say that it is *not* evaluated as a compound block.

Comment: No, it is not "suppressed" in a function.  If the same loop is inside a function, then the value inside does not appear as the final evaluation of a top-level expression.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently the REPL shows the result of every **expression executed as a statement**, not just the outer statement (the for-loop). The for-loop itself does not have any value at all: it is just a statement, not an expression.

Incidentally, you can see the same thing in other constructions, such as an if-statement:

```
if True:
    1 + 2
    "Hello"
```

shows

```
3
'Hello'
```

in the REPL.

Presumably the reason it does not do the same thing for expressions inside functions is that it would produce so much extraneous information that it would only cause confusion.

Comment: ...either that, or expression statements inside functions are not considered part of "interactive mode".

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found something definitive in the Python docs under [expression statements](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html):

> ### 6.1. Expression statements
>
> Expression statements are used (mostly interactively) to compute and write a value, or (usually) to call a procedure (a function that returns no meaningful result; in Python, procedures return the value None). Other uses of expression statements are allowed and occasionally useful. The syntax for an expression statement is:
>
> ```
> expression_stmt ::=  expression_list
> ```
>
> An expression statement evaluates the expression list (which may be a single expression).
>
> In interactive mode, if the value is not `None`, it is converted to a string using the built-in `repr()` function and the resulting string is written to standard output (see section The print statement) on a line by itself. (Expression statements yielding `None` are not written, so that procedure calls do not cause any output.)